# Understanding the dump -H output on AIX

Tags: aix

I executed a dump-H on the libjvm.so file on my AIX system and it came up with the following output, as I understand it the dump command is an equivalent of ldd command on Linux to show the dependent shared libraries, but the below output shows 32 and 64 bit components and i really don't understand what the shr_64.o means ? and does it mean the libi5soenv.so file is not 64 bit ?

`/osxpf/v7r4m0.cuep/bld/shadow/pase.pgm/p5.cuep/compilers/vac1313/opt/IBM/xlc/13.1.3/../../../../usr/lpp/xlC/lib:/osxpf/v7r4m0.cuep/bld/shadow/pase.pgm/p5.cuep/compilers/vac1313/opt/IBM/xlC/13.1.3/lib/aix61:/osxpf/v7r4m0.cuep/bld/shadow/pase.pgm/p5.cuep/compilers/vac1313/opt/IBM/xlC/13.1.3/lib:/osxpf/v7r4m0.cuep/bld/shadow/pase.pgm/p5.cuep/compilers/vac1313/opt/IBM/xlc/13.1.3/lib/aix61:/osxpf/v7r4m0.cuep/bld/shadow/pase.pgm/p5.cuep/compilers/vac1313/opt/IBM/xlc/13.1.3/lib:/osxpf/v7r4m0.cuep/bld/shadow/pase.pgm/p5.cuep/compilers/vac1313/usr/vac/lib/aix53:/afs/rchland.ibm.com/usr8/j9/jdk71-32bit-sdk/sdk/jre/lib/ppc/j9vm:/afs/rchland.ibm.com/usr8/j9/jdk71-32bit-sdk/sdk/jre/lib/ppc:/afs/rchland.ibm.com/usr8/j9/jdk71-32bit-sdk/sdk/jre/../lib/ppc:/usr/lib`

`1 libdl.a       shr_64.o
2 libc_r.a      shr_64.o
3 libi5osenv.so`

Comment: It depends on three shared objects, all of them are 64-bit, the first two live in an .a archive, the third one is standalone.

Comment: Thanks Lorinczy, my exact issue is that iam attempting to start JVM from a C++ code and the JVM crashes as soon as i start it, upon checking for the shared libraries I came up with above list, so does this mean i will need to extract those files from the archive ? so that the JVM can use it ?

Comment: Certainly not, it should work as it is. But you should know that both Java and C++ are huge and both has many quirks (so has AIX) that may clash. If it was me, I'd start  JVM first and call  C-code via JNI.

Comment: Can you please advise how i can debug the JVM crash ?, it generates 3 files namely the core, dump and a trc file, i tried using javadumpviewer on my AIX server to check the dump file but iam not able to understand what those hexa codes mean and how can i find out the reasons why the JVM crashes ?. I can provide the C++ code and the log files for review.

Comment: If you have a `core`  file, you can try `gdb` to examine it: `gdb <executable> core`. Within gdb command `bt` might give some information especially if you compile your program with option `-g`

Comment: i get command not found for gdb, i have the path variables setup though.